# Understanding cufft profiling - Execution pause?

Tags: c++, cuda, profiling, fft

I am currently looking at profiling an application that contains cufft calls. I am using the nvidia visual profiler. Currently there is a gap between the mcpy operation and the execution of the cufft that i dont really understand. For some reason there is a gap of about 0.75+ seconds between memcpy and cufft. At some points there are red lines from "instrumentation"? I am not sure what this means. I suspect this area to be the planning part of the cufft. I am running 2d cufft of 300 batches and using cufftplanmany. I got my suspicion but am not sure. If anyone can enlighten me or point me to a source to find more information about this area i would be happy.

I attached a picture of how it looks.[image: Profiling fft]
The blut part to the right is the cufft execution, brown to the left is memcpy and malloc. I am also wondering why it just says cudafree at the top during the entire process.

Edit: Here is the code. The first part are the memcpy's and malloc's and the second part is the planning and fft execution

```
int TotalSearchSize = TempSearchArea*loadsize;
    int mem_size = sizeof(Complex)* TotalSearchSize;

    cufftComplex *d_signal;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_signal, mem_size));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_signal, imageNew, mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    cufftComplex *d_signal_result;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_signal_result, mem_size));

    cufftComplex *d_filter_kernel;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_filter_kernel, mem_size));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_filter_kernel, tempNew, mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    int rankSize = 2;
    int rank[2];
    rank[0] = TempSearchSizeY; rank[1] = TempSearchSizeX;
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftPlanMany(&plan, rankSize, rank, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, 1, 0, CUFFT_C2C, loadsize);

    printf("Transforming signal cufftExecR2C\n");
    cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex *)d_signal, (cufftComplex *)d_signal, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex *)d_filter_kernel, (cufftComplex *)d_filter_kernel, CUFFT_FORWARD);
```

Best regards

Comment: it's probably initialization time for the cufft library.  It's pretty hard to say if you don't show the corresponding code.

Comment: Okay i will edit this part of the code in.

Comment: Are these the first such calls in your code?  Or do you have other CUFFT and CUDA operations before these?

Comment: These are the first cufft calls. I have cuda calls before this, but it runs as it should.

Comment: The gap is likely cufft library init time. Try putting a cufft sequence that includes an exec call before this code. I think you'll see the gap move to that sequence and disappear from this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making an initial cufft call before the main cufft call, the gap moved. Therefore the gap seen in the image most likely comes from the cufft initialization time.